# How do websites achieve the 'Web 2.0' look and feel?

Tags: ajax

I'm not sure that I'm using the correct language here so I will give some examples of web sites which I believe have 'Web 2.0'look and feel

https://www.yammer.com/

http://www.heroku.com/

https://foursquare.com/

http://24sevenoffice.com/

http://www.formassembly.com

They all have big text, big buttons, plus very slick and tasteful AJAX/CSS.  My question is how is this look and feel assembled?  Some possible ideas I have had:

.  Underlying library such as jQuery/GWT

.  Handled by web framework such as Rails/Django

.  Coded completely from scratch

To me all the sites have sufficient similarity that there does seem to be some type of underlying common mechanism. The reason I'm asking is that as a developer I'm wondering if I can assemble a Web 2.0 looking site using some type of tool kit.

Comment: It's funny how Web 2.0's meaning shifted from "interactive, user-driven content" to "round corners and nice fonts, like the Mac".

Comment: Web 3.0 will introduce *square* corners, where design and content intersect! There are plenty of design guides on the .net, for example, http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/web-design/web-2-0-design-style-guide/, but they are mainly people's *opinion*. Plenty of related questions on the right hand side, too :-)

Comment: How is big text, big buttons, plus very slick and tasteful AJAX/CSS assembled? I think you pretty much answered it right there.

Comment: I've just noticed that yammer are loading all of the assets for their stylesheets etc from a rather interesting subdomain; https://c64.assets-yammer.com - referencing old computers is cool and hence is also Web 2.0 ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are common frameworks and tools to help with the development, sure.  You mention [two](http://jquery.com/) of [them](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/).  However, a tool alone isn't going to do it.  Not unless you just entirely conform to some kind of brown-and-serve framework.  (I don't know of any off-hand.)

Good look and feel comes from good UI/UX design.  I'll bet that each of those example sites you gave has a talented graphic designer behind it (either on staff or contracted for making the site) who is proud of their creative work, and simply used some tools to help facilitate that work.

Answer (score 1):

I have just discovered Bootstrap and this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Bootstrap is the way to go !